# How to make a function that can allow two miss match str in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a function that can allow two mismatch of the letter.

X Y is as below:

```
NKXD QSII
NKXD SIIA
NKXD IIAI
NKXD IAII
NKXD AIIR
NKXD IIRA
```

Here I want to match `in the position of N can be N, or T, or A, or G` and `in the position of K can ne K, or L` and `in the position of D can ne D, or E` and X can be any thing.

**Now getting output (Edit 3)** Like that (Its last line output)

```
((101, 'GDVEKGD'), (215, 'DETF'), (278, 'TKTL'), (400, 'EASSD'))
((101, 'GDVEKGD'), (215, 'DETF'), (278, 'TKTL'), (405, 'RCSAL'))
((101, 'GDVEKGD'), (215, 'DETF'), (278, 'TKTL'), (420, 'EVKAG'))
((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (336, 'QQMG'), (389, 'KKRD'), (420, 'EVKAG'))
((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (358, 'DSER'), (438, 'KLQD'), (495, 'AESAQ'))
((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (358, 'DSER'), (438, 'KLQD'), (499, 'QASAK'))
```

**Edit 2**

Special Letters:

```
N="TAG"
K="L"
D="E"
```

['MASE', 'ASEI', 'SEIH', 'EIHM', 'IHMT']

g4 = 'NKXD'

X can be anything, we want if N is not then check for T, A, G or if K is not then check for L or if D is not then check for E.

our special character is for N == `N, T, A, G and for K == K, Q and for D == D, E but if N is there in this case there is no mismatch. Now I want only special letter mismatch data.

```
MASE - E spl_mismatch, but this not required - M and A is mismatch 
ASEI - A spl_mismatch, S, I is mismatch
EIMH - Here E, I, H mismatch, but only one allow
IHMT - I, H, T is mismatch, but only one allow
```

**For example: please see output above third column:**

`TKTL` - here T, is special mismatch but L is mismatch I don't need, I want only two special mismatch data and `NKXD` X can be anything. these two condition I want in `g4_match` function.

`example: TLKD here T and L is the special mismatch and ALRD here A and L is special mismatch and TKJE - here T and E is special mismatch and NKID this type data here no mismatch or no special mismatch`

**g4_match function**

```
def g4_match(X,Y):
N="TAG"
K="QL"
D="E"
spl_mismatch = 0
for x,y in zip(X,Y):
    #print x, y
    if x == 'N' and y in N:
        if x == 'K' and y in K:
            spl_mismatch += 1
        elif x == 'D' and y in D:
            spl_mismatch += 1  
    else:
        False
if spl_mismatch > 2:
    return False
return True
```

Comment: can you clarify what is spl_mismatch and what is mismatch?

Comment: In spl_mismatch allowing special letter like `in the position of N can be N or T or A or G and in the position of K can ne K or L and in the position of D can be D or E` and in mismatch `X can be anything`

Comment: @jimidime, I have edited my full script, please check once

Comment: edited your g4_match and match.
I got output for matches and matched position like MATCHES ['NKLA', 'EKGD', 'NQND', 'KKRD'] [55, 104, 108, 389]

Comment: Now I getting this only '((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (336, 'QQMG'), (389, 'KKRD'), (420, 'EVKAG'))' but expected output is more

Comment: @jimidime, Please check script once

Comment: what is protein_name?

Comment: Please remove it, its a name of protein I was printing from input csv file

Comment: @jimidime, Please check once more g4_match function I have edited

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
def g4_match(X,Y):
    N="TAG"
    K="L"
    D="E"
    spl_mismatch, mismatch = (0,0)
    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
        if x!=y and x!='X':
            if x == 'N' and y in N:
                spl_mismatch+=1
            elif x == 'K' and y in K:
                spl_mismatch+=1
            elif x == 'D' and y in D:
                spl_mismatch+=1
            else:
                    mismatch+=1
    #print(spl_mismatch,mismatch)
    if mismatch > 1 or spl_mismatch > 1:
            return False
    return True


def match(X,Y):
    mismatch = 0
    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
            if not (x == 'X' or x == y):
                mismatch += 1

    #print(mismatch)
    if mismatch > 1:
        return False
    return True

def find_matches(x,g4_match):
        match_positions = []
        matches         = []
        for i in range(len(protein) - len(x)):
            candidate = protein[i : i + len(x)]
            if match(x, candidate):
                match_positions.append(i)
                matches        .append(candidate)
            elif g4_match(x, candidate):
                match_positions.append(i)
                matches        .append(candidate)
        print("Mmatches: ",matches, match_positions)        
        return matches, match_positions
```

Comment: Thanks but getting error `    mismatch, spl_mismatch = 0

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: I have edited my full script please check once, not getting expected output

Comment: can you show me how spl_mismatch and mismatch being calculated?what should be spl_mismatch and mismatch for X=['NKXD','NKXD','NKXD','NKXD','NKXD'] and 
Y=['QSII','SIIA','IIAI','AIIR','IIRA']

Comment: Please see input name `protein` and I have define four match box's (g1, g3, g4, g5) then made a function H() for calculating the distance and matching the mismatch. In g4_match function I want to give two mismatch allow like(if N is not then search for T, A, G and K is not then search for L and D is not then search for E)

Comment: Dear not getting any output, can you see my full script once, I think I did some mistake there and not able to find out

Comment: @user8866270 check now

Comment: I have tried above code but not getting expected result, result is same as we are getting without g4_match function. I think in my code there is some mistake I did but not able to find out. can you please check once?

Comment: @user8866270 can you explain how spl_mismatch works with an example?

Comment: `spl_mismatch` is use for only special character matching like `N can be N or T or A or G` and `K can be K or L` and `D can be E or D` I want to check the condition for all letters.

Comment: Dear I have edited my new now getting output. There is no match as per special character like `N, T, A, G `etc

Comment: @user8866270 what about now?

Comment: Dear I unable to find out, why our `g4_match` function condition is not working.

Comment: because we are not getting expected output

Comment: @user8866270 ['MASE', 'ASEI', 'SEIH', 'EIHM', 'IHMT', 'HMTG', 'MTGP', 'TGPM'] what should be the value for spl_mismatch and mismatch for those input and how do you calculate? I am trying to help you dear.

Comment: I have edited above please check dear, Yes you are trying to help me, Thanks

Comment: Dear I edited my question please check. I want only `NKXD` means X can be anything and two special mismatch data.. like that example: `TLKD` here T and L is the special mismatch and `ALRD` here A and L is special mismatch and `TKJE` - here T and E is special mismatch and `NKID` this type data here no mismatch or no special mismatch. sorry for the trouble dear.

Comment: @user8866270 in g4match you want to find only special mismatch , if there are more than one special mismatch it will return false otherwise return true. right?

Comment: No, I want at a time two special mismatch and no match data `NKXD` X can be anything. for example: if in the place of N, can be T or can be A or can be G. in the place of K can be L. in the place of D can be E. if NKXD is there so there is no mismatch (X can be anything)

Comment: Is any way for getting expected output. please help, I have tried but not getting dear, sorry for the trouble

Comment: Can you please check once my `g4_match` function below, I have edited. please check once

Answer (score 0):

> One line solution :

```
    X='NKXD'
    Y='TLPD'
    #if you want to check all conditions :

    if Y[0] in {'N','T', 'A', 'G'} and  Y[1] in {'K','L'} and  Y[3] in {'D','E'}:
        print("True")
```

if you want to check if any condition is true:

```
if Y[0] in {'T', 'A', 'G'} or Y[1] in {'K','L'} or  Y[3] in {'D','E'}:
    print("True")
```

There are some error in your code:

> From Ghostly Martijn♦ answer :

You misunderstand how boolean expressions work; they don't work like an English sentence and guess that you are talking about the same comparison for all names here. You are looking for:

```
if Y[0] == 'N' or Y[0] == 'T' or Y[0] == 'A' or Y[0] == 'G':
```

You can shorten that to:

```
if Y[0] in ('N','T','A','G'):
```

or better still:

```
if Y[0] in {'N','T','A','G'}:
```

So as you commented out :

> in the position of N can be N or T or A or G and in the position of K
>   can ne K or L and in the position of D can be D or E and in mismatch X
>   can be anything

You can just use:

```
def g4_match(X,Y):
    spl_match = 0
    if Y[0] == 'N' or Y[0] == 'T' or Y[0] == 'A' or Y[0] == 'G':
        spl_match += 1
    elif Y[1] == 'K' or Y[1] == 'L':
        spl_match += 1
    elif Y[3] == 'D' or Y[3] == 'E':
        spl_match += 1
    if spl_match > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False



print(g4_match('NKXD' ,'TLQE'))
```

Comment: I have edited my full script please check once, not getting expected output

Comment: I have used your code but not getting expected output. I think `g4_match` function is not checking the condition, I am getting output only `match` through function. I have edited my full script please check once

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned `TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable` notifies that you are trying to run a loop on a function which is not correct syntactically.

if you remove the function definition of `spl_match` and indent the code properly, it will start working.

Try the following code

```
def g4_match(X,Y):
    #spl_amino = ['N' == 'N' and 'T' and 'A' and 'G', 'K' == 'K' and 'L', 'D' == 'D' and 'E']

    spl_match = 0
    if Y[0] == 'N' or 'T' or 'A' or 'G':
        spl_match += 1
    if Y[1] == 'K' or 'L':
        spl_match += 1
    if Y[3] == 'D' or 'E':
        spl_match += 1
    if spl_match > 1:
        return False
    mismatch, spl_mismatch = 0, 0
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        if not (x == 'X' and y == x):
                    if (y in spl_amino):
                           spl_mismatch += 1
                    else:
                           mismatch += 1
        if mismatch > 1 or spl_mismatch > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

**P.S**

You are trying to define a function inside function. You started defining a function named `g4_match` and then then you defined another function named `spl_amino`. I dont see a logic behind that. That `spl_amino` function will be defined for that local scope of function `g4_match` and will not be usable outside.

Comment: Can please check my script once?

Comment: I pointed out your issue and suggested a minimal change to your code so it could work when it was initially posted, since youve update the question multiple times, this answer doesnt satisfy what you want now! It surely did when the question was asked yesterday!

Comment: I have also tried your code but same result I was getting

Comment: You would have tried the code after changing the original question, is what i am saying and hence it surely will not work. I will try to update it!

Comment: Could you add input and output cases?
Your question doesnt make it clear, what exactly do you expect

Comment: In my code `protein` is the input like that i have many input but in mean time we are taking only one input. I want to make a function `g4_match` that can match the characters for out conditions like: `in the position of N can be N or T or A or G and in the position of K can be K or L and in the position of D can be D or E and in mismatch X can be anything`. Now i am getting same result as i was getting without `g4_match` function.

Comment: I want to use `g4_match` function only for `L3, pL3 = find_matches(g4, g4_match)`. Now getting output `((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (336, 'QQMG'), (389, 'KKRD'), (420, 'EVKAG'))` this only but I am expecting more output in this`protein` input. Can you please check my edited script ?